# Proverb for: solving a problem creates a bigger one

Tags: idiom-requests, proverbs

Ever heard of a proverb that reflects on "solving a problem creates a bigger one"?

Comment: I would say "opening a can of worms." I don't know of a good reference to back up that intuition, though.

Comment: Also related: [What is the problem that gets worse after you try to solve it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333211/what-is-the-problem-that-gets-worse-after-you-try-to-solve-it) and [Need a word/phrase/proverb for this situation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/376816/need-a-word-phrase-proverb-for-this-situation) and [Expression that means something like “killing the sheep to keep them from being kidnapped”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43585/expression-that-means-something-like-killing-the-sheep-to-keep-them-from-being)

Comment: And [“You not only couldn't fix it but even damaged it more!”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268356/you-not-only-couldnt-fix-it-but-even-damaged-it-more) and [Analogy for arising difficulties](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41848/analogy-for-arising-difficulties)

Comment: Mess up? or SNAFU

Answer (score 9):

***[out of the frying pan (and) into the fire](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+the+frying+pan+into+the+fire)*** suggests the idea that sometime  trying to solve a problem may result in a bigger one:

> Fig. from a bad situation to a worse situation. (*Typically: get ~; go ~; jump ~.)
>
> - When I tried to argue about my fine for a traffic violation, the judge charged me with contempt of court. I really went out of the frying pan into the fire. I got deeply in debt. Then I really got out of the frying pan into the fire when I lost my job.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

Comment: I was looking for something that might include a synonym from "problem" but essentially, this conveys the meaning that I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

[*The cure is worse than the disease* (Wikitionary):](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_cure_is_worse_than_the_disease)

> 2. (*figuratively*) The solution or proposed solution to a problem produces a worse net result than the problem does (or threatens a non-negligible risk of doing so), especially via unintended consequences.

Also *the remedy is worse than the disease* or *the ailment*. Examples from the media:

> The Cure for Fake News Is Worse than the Disease
>    [(Politico, November 12, 2016.)](http://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2016/11/the-cure-for-fake-news-is-worse-than-the-disease-214477)
>
> Fake news is sickening, but don't make the cure worse than the disease
>    [(The Sydney Morning Herald, December 16, 2016.)](http://www.smh.com.au/business/comment-and-analysis/fake-news-is-sickening-but-dont-make-the-cure-worse-than-the-disease-20161216-gtcuew.html)

Both articles acknowledge that fakes news is a problem, but go on to point out that suggested solutions, which would involve giving someone the power to decide what is fake news and what is real news, would be a bigger problem.